# Google Sheets query to select records >= a variable date

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to select records that are `>=` a calculated field. Here is the query:

```
=QUERY('Employer Form Responses'!A:Q,"select * where A >='"&B1&"' ",1)
```

Column `A` in the data is a Date field (e.g. 9/14/2020 18:46:39) and field `B1` contains

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(TODAY()-30),"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

The query gives me an empty result. How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to let a query know that you're comparing a date by simply adding `date` after the comparison operator. Below is that added to the query in your post.

```
=QUERY('Employer Form Responses'!A:Q,"select * where A >= date '"&B1&"' ",1)
```

More info on the weirdness between dates and query here: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/

Comment: Thank you! I think we're getting close. Now I get the error "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Invalid date literal [44060]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd." The 44060 is referring to the value in B1.

Comment: OK - figured out the last bit. I needed to change B1 from =TODAY()-30 TO =TEXT(DATEVALUE(TODAY()-30),"YYYY-MM-DD") to get the data into the format the query expects. Thank you, Jeff Gibson!